# change textField letters with ASCII table

Tags: ios, text

I have a method that changes lowerCase to upperCase

```
- (IBAction)changeText:(id)sender {
_textField2.text = [_textField.text uppercaseString];
}
```

how do I change letters in textField with changing ASCII code value.

for example I enter "abcde", than I add 1 to "a" ASCII code and I get "b". At the end "abcde" should change to "bcdef", or i can enter "привет" and it should change to "ghbdtn".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
- (IBAction)changeText:(id)sender 
{
    _textField2.text = [self changeString];
}

- (NSString *)changeString
{
    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [_textField2.text length]; i++) 
    {
        [str appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [_textField2.text characterAtIndex:i] + 1]]];
    }
    return str; 
}
```

Comment: it didn't help. the textField is empty.

Comment: Suppose, You have set _textField2.text = @"abc" then click a button, if you set changeText: method on button target, then changeString will be called. It will change the _textField2.text value to @"bcd"

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://github.com/MasudShuvo/changeStringOnButtonClick this? or something else?